# What is the use of 2 round parenthesis here in Eric Young's "crypto/conf/conf.h"?

Tags: c

I was unable to understand what do these 2 round parenthesis mean ?

```
struct conf_method_st {
    const char *name;
    CONF *(*create) (CONF_METHOD *meth);
    int (*init) (CONF *conf);
    int (*destroy) (CONF *conf);
    int (*destroy_data) (CONF *conf);
    int (*load_bio) (CONF *conf, BIO *bp, long *eline);
    int (*dump) (const CONF *conf, BIO *bp);
    int (*is_number) (const CONF *conf, char c);
    int (*to_int) (const CONF *conf, char c);
    int (*load) (CONF *conf, const char *name, long *eline);
};
```

I am guessing some sort of type-cast or initialization is going on. Can anyone explain ?

Comment: Its a function pointer my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the syntax for a function pointer type.

Taking the first example:

```
CONF *(*create) (CONF_METHOD *meth);
```

It defines a struct member named `create` which points to a function receiving a single parameter of type `CONF_METHOD*` and returning a value of type `CONF*`

So, for example, if you had a function:

```
CONF *my_create(CONF_METHOD* meth)
{
   //...
}
```

Then you could store a pointer to that function in your struct:

```
struct conf_method_st c;
c.create = my_create;
```

And you can invoke it just like a function:

```
CONF *conf = c.create(meth);
```